# SMTP Mail client settings in app.config file C#

Tags: .net, console, smtp, app-config, mailsettings

I've put mail settings in app.config and can successfully pull them into a mailSettingsSectionGroup object. However, I'm not sure how to send a message using these settings.

This is what I have so far:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =     
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings  = 
config.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as 
System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup;
```

What do I need to do next to use the mailSettings object?

Answer (score 21):

[System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Specifically, the `Send(...)` method. `SmtpClient` will *automatically* pull the details from your app/web.config file. You don't need to do anything to use the configuration, it's all handled automatically.

Edit to add SMTP `Web.Config` Example:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="foo@bar.com">
            <network host="yoursmtpserver.com" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example web.config file or specify the schema that SmtpClient will read?

Comment: How the 'from' is pulled automatically?

Comment: so I specify an address in "from" but when I use another address in the code the address in the code overwrites the one from config. and if I specify nothing in the code (null, empty string) an error is thrown.

Answer (score 5):

I have a custom Class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Configuration;
    using System.Net.Mail;

    namespace MyNameSpace
    {
        internal static class SMTPMailer
        {
            public static void SendMail(string to, string subject, string body)
            {
                Configuration oConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                var mailSettings = oConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;

                if (mailSettings != null)
                {
                    int port = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port;
                    string from = mailSettings.Smtp.From;
                    string host = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
                    string pwd = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password;
                    string uid = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName;

                    var message = new MailMessage
                        {
                            From = new MailAddress(@from)
                        };
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
                    message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(from));
                    message.Subject = subject;
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    message.Body = body;

                    var client = new SmtpClient
                        {
                            Host = host,
                            Port = port,
                            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uid, pwd),
                            EnableSsl = true
                        };

                    try
                    {
                        client.Send(message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
         }
     }
```

And this pulls from my app.conf file just fine.